# How can i plot this in matplotlib with 3 dimensions?

Tags: python, plot, 3d

My data looks like this:

```
Rate    4       8       16      32      64      128     256

David   0.25    0.176   0.652   0.126   0.123   0.142   0.318
Saul    0.132   0.244   0.142   0.162   0.174   0.244   0.149
Maria   0.145   0.189   0.65    0.42    0.111   0.197   0.182
```

I need to plot this data 3d. For clarity, I have 3 dimensions, first one is names like David etc. Secondly the rate, and a variable value for every combination of Name and Rate.
Which kind of plot should I use? I am a little confused because rates and variables are in the same dimension but names are different and when I use regular 3d plot like scatter it said xs, ys and zs should be in the same dimension.

This is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()

ax=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')



X=[1,2,3]

Y=[4,5,6]

Z=[7,8,9]



ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, c='r', marker='o')



ax.set_xlabel('x axis')

ax.set_ylabel('y axis')

ax.set_zlabel('z axis')



plt.show()
```

If we assume X, Y and Z as names, rates and variables, then an error arise about x and y and z should be in the same dimension!

Comment: Take a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org), [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org) in general.

Comment: i know them but what can i do with dimensions error?

Comment: Add that to your question and format appropriately